# How can i extract an object from a javascript script in java

Tags: javascript, java

I have this code:

```
ScriptEngine INTERPRETER = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js");
obj = INTERPRETER.eval("var obj = {a:1, b:2};");
```

So, from the java object obj how can i extract the 2 value form the js object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
 ScriptEngine INTERPRETER = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("js");
 ScriptObjectMirror obj = (ScriptObjectMirror) INTERPRETER.eval("obj = {a:1, b:2};");
 System.out.println(obj.get("b"));
```

Comment: i can't find ScriptObjectMirror class. is it in an external json?

Comment: Its a class from jdk.nashorn.api.scripting package

Comment: ok but eclipse says me that jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.* is empty. do i need to download it from the market place? if yes what should i search?

Comment: do i need to install nashorn from the eclipse marketplace?

Comment: nashorn.jar is part of Java jdk 1.8.0_151

Comment: i have installed java jdk 1.8.0_171 but it still don’t appear

Comment: ok i’ve tried to import the class and also if it return me an error i’ve started the program and it worked. but, why does i give me this error? _Access restriction: the type ‘scriptObjectMirror’ is not API_